# is there any c program that play animation by printing character

Tags: c++, c, linux

I want to use pure c and print some picture in the console, and I use Linux. Is there any examples I can reference? Simply, draw a circle, or complexly, draw a picture. I want to find some source code, Thx!

Comment: Do you mean like ASCII art or actual drawing?

Comment: [`sl`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPMd2dsSVR0&hd=1)

Comment: `telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl`, anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [AA-lib](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aalib/). Or if you need color, [libcaca](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca).